# How to read values from a ROM to control a VGA monitor

Tags: fpga, vhdl, quartus

first I have to say that I'm still a beginner and learning VHDL so any advice is a lot of help.

What I'm trying to do is control an image in a VGA monitor with an FPGA (Cyclone II), using a **.mif** file with the bits corresponding to that image and loading them into a **ROM**, so then I can read the values and show them.

My problem arises when I have to set the ports for the component that I'm using in my code..

```
architecture aa of VGA is

--some signal declarations here

component RomImage is
port(   address : in std_logic_vector(13 downto 0);
        inclock : in std_logic;
        outclock : in std_logic;
        qrom : out std_logic_vector(23 downto 0)
);
end component;

begin

RomIm : lpm_rom
generic map(lpm_file=>"GameOver.mif",lpm_numwords=>9500, lpm_width=>24, lpm_widthad=>14)
port map(address=>address,inclock=>inclock,outclock=>outclock,q=>qrom);

-- other process and logic

-- Output logic (only red, same for blue and green)

redout(9 downto 7) <= qrom(23 downto 21) when x>=225 and x<=415 and y>=250 and y<=300 else
                      rojo(5 downto 3);
```

I don't really know what clock I have to use for the **inclock and outclock**, one of them is to read address and the other for the output q[].
In the design I enter with a 50 MHz clock and then for the VGA clock I divide the frequency to obtain 25 MHz which is the one I need to make the screen work.

I would imagine that the screen sweep has to be synchronized with the frequency at which you have to read the values from the ROM.

Sorry if it's too much code or confusing, I'll try to expand if needed

Answer (score 2):

Been unanswered for a day so let me give it a shot.
That ROM is very unusual. I have been an ASIC engineer for more then 25 years and I have never seen a ROM (or memory) with one port and two clocks. 

Try to find the model for that ROM or find the specs if it is a FPGA library element. Failing that my best guess would be to use the same clock for both ports. You say you are working on VGA which requires 25 MHz so that is probably your pixel clock. Then you must output three analog signals every clock cycle. (And hsync, vsync + pixel clock). Your 24 bit wide ROM is probably RGB as 888 thus you must clock that ROM out at 25 MHz. 
Alternative you could try to use an opposite clock for address and data.

Comment: It looked unusual to me as well at first but when I checked lpm_rom documentation, it's simply that inclock is for registering address bus and outclock is for registering mem content to q. There are dual clock mode & single clock mode available.

Comment: Ah sorry, as Sourabh pointed the inclock is for the address and the outclock is for the output. I see what you mean, next time I can I'll try that and see what happens, but I think I know what I have to do now, thank you!

Comment: Try posting FPGA QUESTION [HERE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/125912/fpga?referrer=M2EwM2FlOWQwMWY3MmExMzFhMGYzYjdhMmZjNWIzYzI2ZTZiZjhmNGU4Y2M4M2JjNDgxZjQyYTIyMzA2MWUwNzX3hnbYNR7EdlfF6m4rBq-JYXjqFwvBDZB5QkiDqKuf0)